# upper bound of p-series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw the following relationship used in a couple of papers: $\sum_{t=2}^\infty \frac{1}{t^\alpha}\le \frac{1}{\alpha-1}$ for $\alpha>1$. Can anyone explain how this relationship is obtained? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the integral test, you have probably seen inequalities like this:
$$
\sum_{t=2}^\infty t^{-\alpha}\le\int_1^\infty t^{-\alpha},\ \ \ \alpha>1
$$
Does the argument make sense from here?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it works.

Comment: Don't forget the $dt$!